# Date extraction JavaScript for Acrobat does not work

Tags: javascript, string, acrobat

Here's the breakdown:
*What code do I need to extract the `12`, `26`, and `48` from a field whose value is `101219488926` and then display it in the format `MM/DD/YY`? (So in this case, the new value would need to be `12/26/48`)*

---

Here's the long version:
I'm using a mag-stripe reader that takes information from the swiped card (a driver license) and then uses that info to auto-populate certain fields in a PDF (first name, last name, date of birth, etc).

Everything works fine, with one exception: the date of birth. Even **that** does *technically* work, but the value is in this format (assuming the person's DOB is 26 December 1948):

10**121948**89**26**

What *I* need is: the month (**12**), day (**26**), and year (19**48**) stripped out of that long number, then converted to display in the format `MM/DD/YY`

Outside of Acrobat, this seems to work just fine:

```
var dob = 101219488926;
trimmonth = dob.substring(2,4);
trimday = dob.substring(10,12);
trimyear = dob.substring(6,8);
dob.value = trimmonth + "/" + trimday + "/" + trimyear;
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The code you have there *shouldn't* work - `substring` is a `String` function, so you would need to convert that number you have to a string for it to be available. Setting `dob.value` is also suspect, since `dob` is a `Number`, and numbers do not have a `value` property.

Of course, it's obvious that you're not showing the actual code you have tried, but something like this would probably work:

```
// Appending blank string to type coerce
var dob = 101219488926 + ''; 

// Array.join to glue the numbers together 
// (no reason why you **have** to use this; the original method will work fine too)
dopInput.value = [dob.substring(2,4), dob.substring(10,12), dob.substring(6,8)].join('/');
```